# Does the Raft consensus protocol handle nodes that lost contact to the leader but not to the other nodes?

Tags: consensus, raft

In case of network partitions, Raft stays consistent. But what does happen if only a single node loses contact *only* to the leader, becomes a candidate and calls for votes?

This is the setup, I adjusted the examples from http://thesecretlivesofdata.com/raft/ to fit my needs:

[image]

Node `B` is the current leader and sends out heartbeats (red) to the followers. The connection between `B` and `C` gets lost and after the election timeout `C` becomes a candidate, votes for itself and asks nodes `A`, `D` and `E` to vote for it (green).

What does happen?

As far as I understand Raft, nodes `A`, `D` and `E` should vote for `C` which makes `C` the next leader (Term 2). We then have two leaders each sending out heartbeats, and hopefully nodes `A`, `D` and `E` will ignore those from `B` because of the lower term.

Is this correct or is there some better mechanism?

Answer (score 3):

After going through the [Raft Paper](https://raft.github.io/raft.pdf) again, it seems that my above approach was correct. From the paper:

> Terms
>   act as a logical clock in Raft, and they allow servers
>   to detect obsolete information such as stale leaders. Each
>   server stores a current term number, which increases
>   monotonically over time. Current terms are exchanged
>   whenever servers communicate; if one server’s current
>   term is smaller than the other’s, then it updates its current
>   term to the larger value. **If a candidate or leader discovers
>   that its term is out of date, it immediately reverts to follower
>   state.** If a server receives a request with a stale term
>   number, it rejects the request

The highlighted part is the one I was missing above. So the process is:

- After node `C` has become candidate, it *increases its term-number to 2* and requests votes from the reachable nodes (`A`, `D` and `E`).
- Those will immediately update their `current_term` variable to 2 and vote for `C`.
- Thus, nodes `A`, `D` and `E` will ignore heartbeats from `B` and moreover tell `B` that the current term is 2.
- `B` will return into follower state (and won't get updated until the network connection between `C` and `B` is healed).

Comment: I believe in practical Raft implementations, there is a pre-step to becoming a candidate where the node asks the others "_if_ I were to become a candidate would you vote for me (are you still connected to a leader)?" In this case, a majority of nodes would respond with "I am still in contact with node D" and so C would not put itself up for election, in order to avoid an unnecessary election cycle.

Comment: When B turns into follower state, and before the network between B and C heals, will B turn into candidates again (because it cannot receive heartbeat from C) and start a new election? If so, the leader will jump between B and C back and forth.

Answer (score 0):

Since A, B, D keeps health heartbeat to the the leader B (Term 1 ), they would not responds to the vote request from C ( Term 2 ), C will timeout and repeat vote and repeat timeout.

> As the Figure 4 from the raft paper https://raft.github.io/raft.pdf 
>   [image]

Answer (score 0):

It depends. First, we define the special Raft ndoe named c1 ,which is not connected with leader,and the current leader is l1, and this is a 3-node raft cluster, the last node named nx.
If c1 can not communicate with the l1 only, it will relaunch election with new term every time, but situations should split apart,

1. The current leader does not commit any log to its followers, but heartbeat from the c1 disconnected from l1,then c1 can only be elected when its term is larger than the majority term. Which is the same for l1(which is not leader now), If the cluster only send heartbeats via the APPENDEntries RPC, the l1 can give the same process like the c1, starting an new election and etc. The best part is that, once the node nx, which can be communicate with everyone, the cluster is more stable.
2. The l1 commits to its follower nx, then the  c1 never be leader even though it relaunch every election and increment term every time. See the Paper http://nil.lcs.mit.edu/6.824/2021/papers/raft-extended.pdf section 5.4 and the Leader Complementness Property. What does the c1 do will be relaunching forever until it resumes the communication with the leader. Here is some good part of the Raft algorihtm. See Figure 2

> In the Rules for all Servers:
> If RPC request or response contains term T > currentTerm; set currentTerm = T, convert to follower.
> This can make a faster convergence in this algorithm, and makes the l1 as new leader at a large probility. The Raft consensum algorithm is good.